# Styling a three-level unordered list

Tags: css

I have a 3-level deep, unordered list I'm styling to create a drop-down menu to extend [this](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/) 2-level simple drop-down menu.  The CSS is as follows:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
/* menu styles */

/* Top-level (Styles Works) */
#jsddm
{   margin: 0;
    padding: 0}

    #jsddm li
    {   float: left;
        list-style: none;
        font: 12px Tahoma, Arial;}

    #jsddm li a
    {   display: block;
        /*background: #324143; Old Style*/
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */;
        padding: 5px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
        width: 70px;
        /*color: #EAFFED; Default color*/
        color: #000099;
        white-space: nowrap;}


    #jsddm li a:hover
    {   background: #24313C}

        /* 2nd-level (Styles Works) */
        #jsddm li ul
        {   margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            visibility: visible;
            border-top: 1px solid white}

            #jsddm li ul li
            {   float: none;
                display: inline}

            #jsddm li ul li a
            {   width: auto;
                background: #dfeffc;
                color: #24313C}

            #jsddm li ul li a:hover
            {   background: #5c9ccc}

                /* 3rd-level (Doesn't apply styles) */
                #jsddm li ul li ul
                {   margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    visibility: hidden;
                    border-top: 2px solid green}
```

The styling works for the first two levels, but not for the 3rd, I'm not sure if I have the syntax correct or if there's something else I'm missing.  The html is as follows:

```
    <div id="dropDownDiv">
        <ul id="jsddm">
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Top Item 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="" class="btn" href="#">2nd Level Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2nd Level Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Top Item 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="" class="btn hide" href="#">2nd Level Item 1</a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="" class="btn hide" href="#">3rd Level Item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a id="" class="btn" href="#">3rd Level Item 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a id="" class="btn" href="#">2nd Level Item 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE:

Thanks for loaning me your eyes Gareth.  Corrected html:

```
        <ul id="jsddm">
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Top Item 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="" class="btn" href="#">2nd Level Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2nd Level Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="btn" href="#">Top Item 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="" class="btn hide" href="#">2nd Level Item 1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="" class="btn hide" href="#">3rd Level Item 1</a></li>
                            <li><a id="" class="btn" href="#">3rd Level Item 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a id="" class="btn" href="#">2nd Level Item 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third level `ul` is not contained within an `li`. That might be causing your problem.

Comment: Aha I see it now, thanks Gareth.  I figured there was some tag somewhere that was missing.